# ASP.NET application slows down under load

Tags: asp.net, iis, etw

I have an ASP.NET application. When I do some load testing, the throughput drops down quite a bit and application performs very slow. I have heard that ETW could be used to trace through the IIS/ASP.NET pipeline that can give you idea where is it taking most of time.

Has anyone used ETW for this context. If so any ideas or links on how this could be configured/used? Any other suggestions are welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about [Event Tracing for Windows is on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751538.aspx).  It includes setup and build information.

Answer (score 1):

Give ANTS a try - it's a solid tool and can be extremely useful even if you don't have a lot of perfomance tuning background:  https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/